# Treelike structure stored in a database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, database-design

So I am working on a book tracking app and I need to store data about the books.  Using objects I would store a list of author objects which would include series objects.  Those would have book objects.

What is the best way to translate this into a database?  Will be using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create your tables based on your Object structure and relationships.

It seems what you have is an `Authors`(table) that has many `Series`(table). `Series` have many `Books`(table). Correct me if I'm wrong, I didn't understand your last sentence that well.

If I am correct then you would need foreign keys as follows:
an `author_id` on your series table, and a `series_id`on your books table to link back to the parent table for queries. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Since an author can write many books and a book can have several authors, there probably needs to be a relationship table (a.k.a. pivot table or junction table).

Comment: Some DMBS also let users enforce foreign key constraints on themselves.  (I.E., you specify a foreign key with a special syntax, and the server will **not** let you modify the table in a way that breaks your constraints; you can not insert a row with a non-existant foreign key (a book with no author), or delete a row that a foreign key is dependent upon (an author that still has books in your database)).  I know that SQLite and MySQL support this.

Comment: Also, depending on what language you are using for backend, you can also specify the foreign key constraints and relationships there.

Comment: Thanks all that is what I was thinking but it seemed a little contrived to me.